# World Map in Cocos2D-Iphone/swift

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Hello I have an image of a world map that has the usa states and every country separated into layers in a psd file.I can then use the psd file in order to create pngs of every country in the world plus the states. Now my cocos2d project i need to have each country and state as its own CCSprite , in order to add color to individual states and countries and so when you tap on a country or state it take you to a new scene that shows information about it. I can't add just the entire world map as one image because then I couldn't colorize individual a countries. But if i add each country as a sprite it would take forever to match them up with the rest of them to put the map back together.Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

absolutely, just export individual states in the full resolution of the world map image. The tool TexturePacker will remove the transparent areas from each state image but remembers the sprites offset, thus all states at same position will naturally align to their intended position.

Without a texture atlas tool this will be a lot more complicated.

Comment: https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker is this the Texture packer tool that you are talking about?